# Stripe Checkout Overlay - Why Fine on Desktop, Not on Mobile?

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

I'm installing Stripe Checkout on my site for the first time, through the Simple Stripe Checkout Wordpress plugin. On my test page, the "Pay With Card" button appears just fine, but when I click it, the overlay with payment form only appears on my desktop. On mobile, it clicks through to a Stripe-hosted page, which is not what I want. Anyone who's interested, or can help, can check it out here:

http://www.radionowhere.net/stripe-test/

I've tried this on 3 different blogs, all with the same results. Am I missing something? Thanks! ~ MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how it works.

Presumably Stripe have decided that mobile devices can't reliably support the overlay, so they launch a new page instead.

You can see it working that way in the demo at https://stripe.com/checkout (and I've just checked my Stripe Checkout, and mine works like this too).

To be honest, I prefer it - on a small screen, on a limited device, it's better to let the checkout take up the whole screen IMHO.